# Extruding faces of a mold. Need to properly assign vertices to triangles

Tags: unity, mesh, 3d-modeling

So I am creating a sort of modelling app using Unity. The user is able to select some vertices (using these vertexHandle GameObjects) and from there, extrude the face surrounded by these vertices.

My process for this currently is:

1.Copy the selected vertices, and clone them a unit above. Add them to the array of vertices that the mesh pulls from

2.Check to see if there are any triangles that every vertex was selected. These triangles would be inside the mesh, and so they are deleted (Though for some reason, this is not working).

3.Iterate through the selected and new vertices, connecting them with triangles (I'm not sure how to properly attempt this at all, though I tried)

Here is my code:

```
public class ExtrudeScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Material defaultMat;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void ExtrudeFaces() 
{
    //Find all vertex handles
    GameObject[] vertexHandles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("VertexHandle");

    //List of Vectors to store the current vertices
    List<GameObject> vertList = new List<GameObject>();

    //Sort through all of them and gets selected vertices
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexHandles.Length; i++)                                      
    {
        //Gets the ObjectVertex script for each and checks if is selected
        ObjectVertex ov = vertexHandles[i].GetComponent<ObjectVertex>();                
        if (ov.isSelected)                                                            
        {
            vertList.Add(vertexHandles[i]);
        }
    }


    //Creates a list of vectors from the vertices
    List<Vector3> vectorList = new List<Vector3>();
    GameObject mesh = GameObject.Find("Object");
    Mesh meshData = mesh.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;       //Gets the object's mesh filter
    Vector3[] vertEdit = meshData.vertices;                     //Grabs the list of the object's vertices
    List<Vector3> meshVertList = vertEdit.ToList();             //Creates list of all vertices
    List<int> triList = meshData.triangles.ToList();            //Creates list of all triangles
    List<int> connectList = new List<int>();                    //List to store nums of old and new vert array positions


    int newVertCount = meshVertList.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertList.Count; i++) 
    {
        //Creates list of new vertice vectors, vertexNum is the vertex's assigned num in the mesh's array of vertices
        vectorList.Add(vertEdit[vertList[i].GetComponent<ObjectVertex>().vertexNum]);
        vectorList[i] += (Vector3.up);

        //Add new vertices to mesh
        meshVertList.Add(vectorList[i]);

        //Adds the new and connected verts to an array
        newVertCount++;
        connectList.Add(vertList[i].GetComponent<ObjectVertex>().vertexNum);
        connectList.Add(newVertCount);
    }

    bool vertA = false;
    bool vertB = false;
    bool vertC = false;

    //Delete covered triangles
    //Cycles through triangles
    for (int i = 2; i < triList.Count; i += 3) 
    {
        //Cycles through selection, checking if the vertice is in it
        for (int j = 0; j < vertList.Count; j++) 
        {
            if (i == vertList[j].GetComponent<ObjectVertex>().vertexNum)
            {
                vertA = true;
            }

            if ((i - 1) == vertList[j].GetComponent<ObjectVertex>().vertexNum) 
            {
                vertB = true;
            }

            if ((i - 2) == vertList[j].GetComponent<ObjectVertex>().vertexNum) 
            {
                vertC = true;
            }
        }

        //If all vertices were in the selection, delete the triangle
        if ((vertA) && (vertB) && (vertC)) 
        {
            triList.Remove(i);
            triList.Remove(i-1);
            triList.Remove(i-2);

            i -= 3;
        }

        vertA = false;
        vertB = false;
        vertC = false;
    }

    //Attach new faces with triangles
    for (int i = 0; i < vertList.Count; i++) 
    {
        triList.Add(connectList[i]);
        triList.Add(connectList[i + 1]);
        triList.Add(connectList[i + vertList.Count - 1]);
    }

    //Refresh Mesh
    meshData.vertices = meshVertList.ToArray();                                     //Assigns the vertices
    meshData.triangles = triList.ToArray();                                         //Assigns the triangles
    meshData.RecalculateBounds();                                                   //Recalculates the object size
    meshData.RecalculateNormals();                                                  //Recalculates the object normals

    mesh.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = defaultMat;                            //Sets mat to the default mat
}
}
```

I know that number 2 is on the cusp of working, and there's probably something small that I'm missing that's preventing the triangles from being removed. But I can't figure out part three at all. Does anyone know what to do?